# What's the proper way to fix this type error?

Tags: javascript, typescript, environment-variables, typeerror

What's the proper way to fix this? I don't want to just cast or make a copy of the array, converting `undefined` to an empty string or something like this. I guess it's hacky. What's the proper way to fix this?

```
Type 'ProcessEnv' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
  'string' index signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
node-pty.d.ts(45, 5): The expected type comes from property 'env' which is declared here on type 'IPtyForkOptions | IWindowsPtyForkOptions'
```

code:

```js
import { IPty, spawn } from 'node-pty';

    ptyProcess = spawn(shell, [], {
      name: 'xterm-color',
      cols: 80,
      rows: 30,
      cwd: process.env.HOME,
      env: process.env // error comes from this assignment
    });
```

**EDIT 1:**

Currently I'm doing this:

```
interface INonUndefinedEnv {
  [key: string]: string
}

const safeEnv = () => {
  let o:INonUndefinedEnv = {};
  for(const [key, value] of Object.keys(process.env).entries())
      o[key] = value ?? ""; // make sure it's string and never undefined
  return o;
}
```

then I can do:

```
ptyProcess = spawn(shell, [], {
  name: 'xterm-color',
  cols: 80,
  rows: 30,
  cwd: process.env.HOME,
  env: safeEnv() // type match
});
```

But I'd like to avoid all this loop if possible...

Answer (score 2):

I think the way you did it is not hacky. It's the right thing to do. The hacky thing to do would be to look into node-pty's source code to see if undefined values could cause an issue and using "as any" if they couldn't. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [interface](https://github.com/microsoft/node-pty/blob/main/typings/node-pty.d.ts#L45) and the error given you would need to do this:

```
    import { IPty, spawn } from 'node-pty';

    ptyProcess = spawn(shell, [], {
      name: 'xterm-color',
      cols: 80,
      rows: 30,
      cwd: process.env.HOME,
      env: { myEnv: process.env }
    });
```

And you could change "myEnv" to whatever.

Comment: I don't get how this solves the error... you mean recreate the whole array like `{PATH: process.env.PATH}` and so on?

Comment: The `env` property needs to match this type: `{ [key: string]: string; }`

Comment: I know that, I know I can make a type like `interface MyType { [key: string]: string; }` then cast `process.env as MyType` but I'm looking for the proper way to do that because when it's `undefined` but I faked it as `string` I may get some error somewhere

Comment: If it's undefined, it would throw the same error as an empty string `''`, so why not set it as that if process.env is undefined

Comment: i mean library internal uses like `let s = env[x];` where the code later does something like `s.length` assuming `s` is a `string` when it`s `undefined`, that would end up in a error. that's why i'm afraid of just cast it

Comment: You can't just "cast it" everytime though, they have to be overlapping types. I don't know what value you have for `process.env`, but clearly you have to match the expected type. You will have to guard against undefined by not calling `spawn` unless thats defined.